# Quick sum of all rows that fill a condition in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,1, 0], [5, 1, 4], [7, 8, 9]]),columns=['a','b','c'])

   a  b  c
0  1  1  0
1  5  1  4
2  7  8  9
```

I want to find the first column in which the majority of elements in that column are equal to 1.0.

I currently have the following code, which works, but in practice, my dataframes usually have thousands of columns and this code is in a performance critical part of my application, so I wanted to know if there is a way to do this faster.

```
for col in df.columns:
    amount_votes = len(df[df[col] == 1.0])
    if amount_votes > len(df) / 2:
       return col
```

In this case, the code should return 'b', since that is the first column in which the majority of elements are equal to 1.0

Comment: Shouldn't be the column `b`? Because it's first to have two `1`

Comment: No, column 'a' is [1,1,0], 'b' is ['5','1','4'].

Comment: If you do `print(df)` you will see column `a` has only one `1`. Do you mean row?

Comment: I think you might have messed up the sample frame constructor @GeorgeFrancis

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct, the expected output,in this case would be 'b'. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
print((df.eq(1).sum() > len(df) // 2).idxmax())
```

Prints:

```
b
```

Answer (score 0):

Find columns with more than half of values equal to 1.0

```
cols = df.eq(1.0).sum().gt(len(df)/2)
```

Get first one:

```
cols[cols].head(1)
```